# Programmatically add a TextBlock to a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock x:Name="Txt" Text="{Binding fieldA}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

I want to do the equivalent of the above XAML programatically (There is more to the XAML, I have only shown the relevant bits). So far I have got:

```
DataTemplate newDataTemplate = new DataTemplate();
TextBlock newTextBlock = new TextBlock();
newTextBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("fieldA"));
newTextBlock.Name = "txt";
```

So how do I now add the TextBlock to the DataTemplate.. i.e. I want to do something like:

```
newDataTemplate.children.Add(TextBlock)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var newTextBlock = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
newTextBlock.Name = "txt";
newTextBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("fieldA"));
DataTemplate newDataTemplate = new DataTemplate(){VisualTree = newTextBlock};
```

I think you should look at this question.

[How do I create a datatemplate with content programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427972/how-do-i-create-a-datatemplate-with-content-programmatically)

Comment: this isn't working.. the TextBlock never makes it to the DataTemplate's tree surely there is a way to just slap the TextBlock into the DataTemplate's tree.

Comment: @trideceth12: By the way, [this is deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory.aspx).