# Add image to ListView C# WPF (without xaml)

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

How can I make an image item in ListView? I need to do it without xaml, only C#. I was surfing about 40 min about it and have nothin found.
I've tried a lot of things and i stopped here
in first column i see just "System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel".

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GridView grView = new GridView();
        GridViewColumn gwCol1 = new GridViewColumn();
        GridViewColumn gwCol2 = new GridViewColumn();
        gwCol1.Header = "Avatar";
        gwCol2.Header = "Name";
        gwCol2.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("name");
        gwCol1.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("stack");
        grView.Columns.Add(gwCol1);
        grView.Columns.Add(gwCol2);
        listView1.View = grView;
        //
        var list = new List<XData>();
        listView1.ItemsSource = list;
        // 
        BitmapImage image1 = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\montana\OneDrive\Pictures\Saved Pictures\WVQfZqY.jpg"));
        Image img = new Image();
        img.Width = 100;
        img.Height = 100;
        img.Source = image1;
        StackPanel stackPanel1 = new StackPanel();
        stackPanel1.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        stackPanel1.Children.Add(img);
        list.Add(new XData() { name="hola", stack=stackPanel1 });

    }
}


class XData
{
    public string name { get; set; }
   // public string url { get; set; }
    public StackPanel stack { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: *"without xaml"* is contradictory as you have some `listView1` here which is simply lacking datatemplate (itemtemplate?). Without it you have to [create `ListBoxItem`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13267883/1997232) explicitly (passing bitmap as its `Content`) instead of passing some `List<>` as `ItemsSource`..

Comment: Besides that, you should either use an ObservableCollection instead of a List, or add items before you assign the List to the ItemsSource property.

Comment: And why do you create the GridView and its columns in code behind when the ListView itself is declared in XAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something what produce wanted result.

[image]

---

Change `XData` definition to avoid having view elements there (you didn't mention MVVM, but it's good to stick to):

```
class XData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can either define data template in xaml (common solution) or [generate it in code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8430451/1997232) like this:

```
var factory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Image));
factory.SetValue(Image.SourceProperty, new Binding(nameof(XData.Path)));
factory.SetValue(Image.WidthProperty, 100.0);
factory.SetValue(Image.HeightProperty, 100.0);
var dataTemplate = new DataTemplate { VisualTree = factory };
```

Data template can be as complicated as you like, but obviously defining it in xaml and then loading with `FindResource()` is way easier, consider to use this option instead.

And then this datatemplate has to be specified as `CellTemplate` like this:

```
GridView grView = new GridView();
grView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn { Header = "Avatar", CellTemplate = dataTemplate });
grView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn { Header = "Name", DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(nameof(XData.Name)) });
listView1.View = grView;
```

**Note**: you shouldn't use `DisplayMemberBinding` for column with `CellTemplate`.

Now, finally, you can fill `ListView` by setting its `ItemSource` as usual:

```
var list = new List<XData>();
list.Add(new XData { Name = "hola", Path = @"c:\temp\1.jpg" });
list.Add(new XData { Name = "hola2", Path = @"c:\temp\2.png" });
listView1.ItemsSource = list;
```

Comment: Thanks. But, how can I replace nameof? im using visual studio 2012

Comment: Instead of `nameof(somemember)` use `"somemember"` (in your case it's `"Name"` and `"Path"` appropriately).

Comment: Working) Thanks again!